# MongoDB $elemMatch with 2 properties condition

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have documents with this structure:

```
{
    "_id": 5863635009,
    "players": [{
        "hero_id": 10,
        "slot": 132
    }, {
        "hero_id": 16,
        "slot": 131
    }, {
        "hero_id": 1,
        "slot": 130
    }, {
        "hero_id": 7,
        "slot": 129
    }, {
        "hero_id": 75,
        "slot": 128
    }, {
        "hero_id": 21,
        "slot": 4
    }, {
        "hero_id": 123,
        "slot": 3
    }, {
        "hero_id": 114,
        "slot": 2
    }, {
        "hero_id": 68,
        "slot": 1
    }, {
        "hero_id": 84,
        "slot": 0
    }]
}
```

I have to find all documents where 2 particular heroes present AND one of them should have slot <= 127 AND another one should have slot >= 128 (can't have slot <= 127 or >= 128 both at the same time)

For example I search for hero_id 10 and 114. hero_id=10 should have slot <= 127 while hero_id=114 slot >=128 OR hero_id=10 should have slot >= 128 while hero_id=114 slot <= 127

As I'm new to Mongo I'm not sure how to go further than this and then check manually results for the slots condition:

```
{players : {$elemMatch: {hero_id : 10, hero_id : 114} }}
```

Is it possible to do inside the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The literal translation to mongo query laguage:

```
db.collection.find({
  $or: [
    {
      "$and": [
        {
          "players": {
            "$elemMatch": {
              "hero_id": 10,
              "slot": { "$lte": 127 }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "players": {
            "$elemMatch": {
              "hero_id": 114,
              "slot": { "$gte": 128 }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    { the alternative "or" condition goes here. It is very similar}
  ]
})
```

Comment: Ohh, thanks a lot! I had no idea it has logical operators like these and was pretty sure people do it outside of a query, I will go take a course on Mongo XD